# Views pager shows an incorrect current page

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have a page view displaying a table of fields with a few exposed filters.  This page view also has a full pager (8 items per page). The view is not using AJAX, nor does it have any caching enabled (currently).

When on the view page, using the pager to navigate to specific pages, or next/last page works fine (since the pager adds the "?page=N" query argument).  However, the issue I am experiencing is that if I try to navigate from any other page back to page 1 (so the view does not pass "?page=" as an argument), the pager is "stuck" displaying the last page I was on as the current page. The results listed are correct (displays the results for page 1), it is just the pager is displaying the wrong page as selected.

On the first page of results, I click on the pager link to go to page 3; page reloads with results of page 3, and the pager shows page 3 as current page. I then click on the pager link to go to "<< first". The page reloads with the results of page 1; however, the pager still shows page 3 as the current page.

A few more details, I am using a custom theme with custom CSS to style the pager (but css should not interfere with the pager). I am not altering the pager at all in my template.php, nor do I have a custom pager.tpl.php.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I am not sure if it is specific to a views pager, or just the Drupal pager in general. I have no idea what could be causing the problem.

I am using Drupal 7.21 and Views 7.x-3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue for a view block when I had caching enabled on the view and block caching enabled under Performance. Try disabling the page caching under Performance.

Comment: I have turned off all caching and compressing. Also, if it was a caching issue then I assume the page results would also be incorrect and not just the pager display. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you tried [Views litepager](https://drupal.org/project/views_litepager)

Comment: I have not tried views litepager, but would like to keep using the views core full pager.